# multiple polygons, InfoWindow, setMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

well, I've spent a while on this, and I've stumbled my way through and got this far with the help of many tutorials and examples.

I need to create multiple polygons each with a separate InfoWindow. Think I've got that but having trouble with setMap. This is how far I've got:

Getting a type error

```
object #<object> has no method 'setMap'
```

How can I fix this error?

```
<script>
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);

  // Let's start with an empty object:
var countries = {    
};

// Now let's add a county polygon:
countries['UK'] = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(59.677361, -2.469846),
    new google.maps.LatLng(59.299717,   -6.314917),
    new google.maps.LatLng(57.877247,   -9.314917),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.428078,  -11.638861),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.784554,  -11.702241),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.185848,  -10.054354),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.405380,   -7.012100),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.090675,   -3.272664),
    new google.maps.LatLng(48.775970,   -1.709283),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.757851,   -2.089565),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.714554,    1.037195),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.482437,    2.304801),
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.433609,    3.276632),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.863132,    3.445646)
    // ...
  ],
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.3
});

// Next county:
countries['FR'] = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    // This is not real data:
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.757370),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
    // ...
  ],
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.3
});

// And so on...

countries.setMap(map)

;
  // Add a listener for the click event
  google.maps.event.addListener(UK, 'click', showInfoUK);
  google.maps.event.addListener(FR, 'click', showInfoFR);

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

function showInfoUK(event) {
    var contentString = "<b>UK</b><br />";
        contentString += "UK, Channel Islands, Ireland";



  // Replace our Info Window's content and position
  infowindow.setContent(contentString);
  infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infowindow.open(map);
}
function showInfoFR(event) {
    var contentString = "<b>FR</b><br />";
        contentString += "France, N,W";



  // Replace our Info Window's content and position
  infowindow.setContent(contentString);
  infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infowindow.open(map);
}

</script>
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: damn! I get an error with setMap

Comment: javascript arrays do not have a .setMap() method. google.maps.Polygon() objects do. Additionally, there are no associative arrays in javascript, such as countries['UK'].

Comment: I see, so I've got it all completely wrong then!?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have references to keys like for example php, so countries['UK'] is not possible to set. You have to use numeric keys. So syntax should be something like this:

```
countries[0] = new google.maps.Polygon({ ... });
countries[1] = new google.maps.Polygon({ ... });
```

I made your example working:

http://jsfiddle.net/AcCzT/15/

Can be finetuned. It's not perfect. It's just a quick fix. 
You can go on from there

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. However when I upload it I get an error with main.js:

    object has no method 'Load'

Comment: Are you including google maps api js correctly? main.js is the main file Google uses. What's your initialize code?

Comment: Hi ferry, ive used your code from the fiddle to create over 300 polygons (UK county boundaries). However i am unsure on how to give the popups the information they need i cant at the moment get it to pop up.

With the code here its hard coded for each new info window and a matching function. do i need to include the function in my foreach loop and dynamically create that too?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays do not have a `.setMap()` method. google.maps.Polygon() objects do. Additionally, there are no associative arrays in javascript, such as countries['UK']

This might work:

```
countries['UK'].setMap(map);
```

but it wouldn't be correct.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that earlier but it got reference error uk is not defined.

Comment: You can only get that error message if you leave out the quotes, like countries[UK], not with countries['UK'], but anyway, **there are no associative arrays in Javascript**

Answer (score 0):

use ajax easier, more plain.
for example,

```
downloadUrl("url", function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
        ........
        var decodedPath = ........
        polygon.setMap(map);
        ........
    }
});
```

Comment: do not post the direct link.... write some of the codes in your answer...or expalin ..

Comment: thank you for the example but not much use as I can't see your code to be able to see how you've done it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. What Marcelo said, to add the polygon to the map, use: `countries["UK"].setMap(map);`
2. To add the click listener, you need to reference the polygon: `google.maps.event.addListener(countries["UK"], 'click', showInfoUK);`

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_countryPolygons.html)